# How to ensure an SDL2 fullscreen window is ready with Python (pysdl2)?

Tags: python, sdl-2, pysdl2

When generating a new fullscreen window, vis-a-vis:

```
sdl2.SDL_Init(sdl2.SDL_INIT_VIDEO)
window = sdl2.ext.Window('win_name', (x_size, y_size), (0, 0), <<flags>>)
```

If I begin loading resources, or blitting to the graphics buffer immediately,  the window may or may not be ready; the time this takes seems entirely contingent on the interim processing overhead.

Is there a callback or some means of knowing that the screen is fully ready? I've gone through the `pysdl2` docs and found nothing promising, but I get lost in the `sdl2` docs pretty quickly because I'm not a `C` programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no callback to know if the windows is ready because there is no need for it.

When the `sdl2.ext.Window()` returns, you're guaranteed that the window itself is ready.

However, graphics that you put in that window might not be ready and in that case, you should load graphics and call `window.show()` after it has been loaded.